# Numpy Image Arrays: How to efficiently switch from RGB to Hex

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have been using nested for loops to turn RGB images into an image array of Hex values, but it is too slow for large images. Does anyone know a quick way and or a library that can help me switch back and from RGB to HEX?

edit:
@ragingSloth

This is what I came up with but it is too slow for what I need:

```
def rgb_to_hex(array):
    (x, y, z) = array.shape
    for v in range(0, x):
        for u in range(0, y):
            array[v, u] = int('%02x%02x%02x' % (array[v, u, 0], array[v, u, 1], array[v, u, 2]))
```

Comment: how are you doing it? opencv might have something for you.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not the world's greatest at python, so I have to ask: What is a Hex image?

Comment: @ragingSloth this is what I came up with crudely, it is very slow!def rgb_to_hex(array):
    (x, y) = array.shape
    for v in range(0, x):
        for u in range(0, y):
            array[v, u] = int('%03d%03d%03d' % (array[v, u, 1], array[v, u, 2], array[v, u, 3]))

Comment: @beaker By Hex I mean a hexidecimal value for the RGB colour. So an RGB of say (123, 456, 789) would be in Hex: 7BFFFF. this may help if you don't know about hex colours: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm

Comment: @user2909415 Ah, so you're really talking about color strings and not so much about a hex "image". Then why are you turning it back into an int? Also, it would be better if you edited your question to add your code. It's kind of hard to read in the comments.

Comment: @beaker if 'hex image' is an unusual expression then I will edit the question.

Comment: So you're trying to get the 3 RGB values and pack them into a single int?

Comment: @beaker yes that is the real goal. If you can do it as a six digit decimal I can work with that too, but yes the idea is from 3 RGB to one single int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using beaker's idea, you can also eliminate the double for-loop:

```
def tohex(array):
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype='uint32')
    return ((array[:, :, 0]<<16) + (array[:, :, 1]<<8) + array[:, :, 2])
```

Comment: Very cool... I like the vectorized bits. I think I need to look some more into Python! :D

Answer (score 5):

String operations are probably pretty slow. A direct mathematical approach would be:

```
array[v, u] = ((array[v, u, 0]<<16) + (array[v, u, 1]<<8) + array[v, u, 2])
```

This combines the 3 bytes of the RGB representation into a single int:

```
>>> A = [123, 255, 255]
>>> B = (A[0]<<16) + (A[1]<<8) + A[2]
>>> B
8126463
>>> hex(B)
'0x7bffff'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is much faster, but you could do something like this:

```
hexarr = np.vectorize('{:02x}'.format)
```

And then run it on an RGB array:

```
In [67]: a = (np.random.rand(2,5,3)*255).astype('u1')

In [68]: a
Out[68]:
array([[[149, 145, 203],
        [210, 234, 219],
        [223,  50,  26],
        [166,  34,  65],
        [213,  78, 115]],

       [[191,  54, 168],
        [ 85, 235,  36],
        [180, 140,  96],
        [127,  21,  24],
        [166, 210, 128]]], dtype=uint8)

In [69]: hexarr(a)
Out[69]:
array([[['95', '91', 'cb'],
        ['d2', 'ea', 'db'],
        ['df', '32', '1a'],
        ['a6', '22', '41'],
        ['d5', '4e', '73']],

       [['bf', '36', 'a8'],
        ['55', 'eb', '24'],
        ['b4', '8c', '60'],
        ['7f', '15', '18'],
        ['a6', 'd2', '80']]],
      dtype='|S2')
```

You can collapse the third dimension with `view`:

```
In [71]: hexarr(a).view('S6')
Out[71]:
array([[['9591cb'],
        ['d2eadb'],
        ['df321a'],
        ['a62241'],
        ['d54e73']],

       [['bf36a8'],
        ['55eb24'],
        ['b48c60'],
        ['7f1518'],
        ['a6d280']]],
      dtype='|S6')
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be a whole lot faster (just over twice as fast):

```
In [89]: timeit rgb_to_hex(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.83 s per loop

In [90]: timeit hexarr(a).view('S6')
1 loops, best of 3: 2.54 s per loop
```