# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1048576 into shape (1024,1024,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, faster-rcnn

The below is a code snippet from a .ipynb file.

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  print(image_path)  
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  print('yooo')  
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  print(image_np)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
```

I'm trying to test the accuracy of my model on a dataset of images. from the above code I'm getting the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ee1cf025b3f1> in <module>
      6   # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      7   # result image with boxes and labels on it.
----> 8   image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      9   print('yooo')
     10   print(image_np)

<ipython-input-15-af094dcdd84a> in load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      2   (im_width, im_height) = image.size
      3   return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
----> 4       (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1048576 into shape (1024,1024,3)
```

Can someone please help me to solve this error?

Comment: 1024*1024*3 = 3145728 != 1048576

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how can I solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two way of encoding pixels:

1- You use an hex code to represent the value of the color

2- You use a triplet of values between 0 and 255

here you have a 1024*1024 = 1048576 pixels meaning it has been coded on hex values and you are trying to load it to a matrix of shape (1024,1024,3) meaning that it is the representation of the RGB triplet.

How to solve it:
reshape to (1024,1024) then expand to (1024,1024,3) by exploding the hex formula into three values (RGB).([here is a way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226354/numpy-image-arrays-how-to-efficiently-switch-from-rgb-to-hex),
`if image.format == "PNG":image = image.convert('RGB')` as been proposed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3718) as a work around this issue